# When traveling from Barcelona to San Francisco my first stop is in Miami. Are my bags checked there or at my final stop in San Francisco

Tags: customs-and-immigration

Will I have to clear customs in Florida when traveling from Barcelona to San Francisco via Florida. Will my bags go through directly to San Francisco?

Comment: Of course, you need to make sure you are actually allowed to travel to the US. Only US citizens and permanent residents and a limited number of other exceptions (spouses, children…) are currently allowed to travel to the US from Spain.

Answer (score 5):

Your checked bags will be tagged to the destination (San Francisco). However, in Miami, you will go through immigration, pick up your checked bags, carry your checked bags through customs, and then give your (already tagged) checked bags to the airline after customs (usually at a place specifically for people coming out of customs to do that), and those bags will be checked to San Francisco for you to pick up.

Answer (score 1):

You and your bags will pass through US Immigration and Customs in Miami.